# Windows Server 2008 r2 FTP blocking outside connections

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, ftp

I have a windows server 2008r2 running IIS 7.5. I am trying to setup a FTP-server in IIS but I'm running into some annoying problems.

Setting up the server works fine but when I try to connect from a remote client the connection times out. I have tried to connect to the FTP-server from the localhost and it works flawlessly.

I figured that it should be some trouble with the firewall so I went into firewall settings and disabled the Public Profile and my remote connections worked!

In my inbound rules there are rules for FTP-connections to allow all profiles etc. I guess they are made automatically when setting up the FTP-server.

Anyone got any idea how to allow remote connections without turning off the public firewall?

Comment: If you use active FTP, create an additional FW rule, allowing inbound tcp-connections on port 20 as well

Comment: As Mathias suggested created a rule for port 21 in the Windows Advaned Firewall coniguration manager. This should get you started http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545423

Comment: There is already an inbound rule which allows traffic on port 21. I also tried to open up port 20 but that didn't do any good.

Answer (score 1):

can you show the relevant rules with command

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all
```

what you basically want is for active ftp ports 21 incoming (from any port), and port 20 (data) outgoing to any port.
For passive ftp, you'd need to allow incoming ports of the given range (set up on IIS) and allow them in the firewall too.

have a look at this guide [Configuring FTP Firewall Settings in IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/309/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings-in-iis-7/) i think it'll be very helpful.